# How to run electron on a localhost server in Build as well as in Dev

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, next.js

I'm developing with `Next.js + Electron + Typescript`.
I'm using the `npx create-next-app --example with-electron-typescript` command to generate code.

`npm run dev` (the contents are `npm run build-electron && electron .` ), it seems that the local server is up and running on localhost8000, but when build, the server is not up internally, and it is running by directly accessing the file.

However, some APIs do not work correctly if there is no domain in the `location.origin` , so it works in Dev, but does not work in Build.

So, if it is possible, I would like to run the server on localhost in the build version as well as in the Dev version.
Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Can you show us where/how you fire those requests, and tells us which APIs you are talking about?

Comment: I'm trying to use Skyway.js
To use this service, it is required to allow a specific domain.

https://webrtc.ecl.ntt.com/en/documents/javascript-sdk.html#_1-preparation

Comment: Did you ever find a solution ? I also need this. I think you are using Nextron like me.

There is answer below, but unfortunately it is somewhat different with what Nextron file has

Answer (score 3):

It's not shown in any of the examples, even though someone requested one:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28225

It is possible using a custom server:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

You can follow these steps to create one:

1. Clone the Electron Next TypeScript example repo:
   https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-electron-typescript
2. Update `./electron-src/index.ts` with the following code:

```
import isDev from 'electron-is-dev';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import next from 'next';
import { parse } from 'url';

app.on('ready', async () => {

  // Use server-side rendering for both dev and production builds
  const nextApp = next({
    dev: isDev,
    dir: app.getAppPath() + '/renderer'
  });
  const requestHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

  // Build the renderer code and watch the files
  await nextApp.prepare();

  // Create a new native HTTP server (which supports hot code reloading)
  createServer((req: any, res: any) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    requestHandler(req, res, parsedUrl)
  }).listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/')
```

3. Update `./package.json` Electron build configuration to include the renderer src files:

```
  "build": {
    "asar": true,
    "files": [
      "main",
      "renderer"
    ]
  }
```

4. In `./package.json` move `next` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`. This means it will be available to run in production builds

Then use helpful scripts to unpack the binary and see the files/folder inside:

```
npx asar extract ./dist/mac/ElectronTypescriptNext.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar ./dist/unpack
```

Run the unpacked version to debug:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron ./dist/unpack
```

I have created an Express Server version and NextJS versions to prove it is possible:
https://github.com/kmturley/electron-server/tree/feature/express
https://github.com/kmturley/electron-server/tree/feature/next